# Tailwind css grid layout

Tags: css, tailwind-css

I am trying tailwind css for my mini project to achieve below layout with grid.

**My expectations**

[image]

**What I have achieved**

[image]

**Below is my code**

```
<div id="main" class="container grid grid-row-3 grid-flow-col gap-1">
    <div class="bg-blue-500 row-span-3">
        <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue-500 row-span-2">
        <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
    </div>
    <div class="bg-blue-300">
        <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To attain your design guide goals, you can use **flex system classes** easily as the following code

```
  <div class="flex flex-col p-3">
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="m-1">
                <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
            </div>
            <div class="m-1">
                <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
            </div>
            <div class="m-1">
                <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
            </div>
            <div class="m-1">
                <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="flex">
            <div class="flex grow  m-1">
                <img class="w-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
            </div>
            <div class="flex flex-col m-1 basis-1/4 ">
                <div class="m-1">
                    <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
                </div>
                <div class="m-1">
                    <img class="" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Make sure that your small images dimensions to be **square** for more proper display. **Enjoy**!

Answer (score 0):

Layout created tailwind css 3 Grid system

```
<div id="main" class="container grid grid-cols-4 grid-rows-3 gap-2">
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500 col-span-3 row-span-2">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
  <div class="bg-blue-500">
    <img class="object-cover w-full h-full" src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0574/6937/0528/files/banner_1.jpg?v=1643371619;" />
  </div>
</div>
```